# Get year from string datetime in Spark SQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I was trying to get the year in spark SQL by using the **year()** function from the documentation.

The datetime string called `dt` is formatted like `dd/MM/yyyy`.

I have tried to do a query like below for get all the record of 2018 and 2019 years:

```
SELECT * FROM T1
WHERE year(dt) == 2018 AND year(dt=='2019');
```

But it seems that something is wrong. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did it work? Let me know if I can help further.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are asking something that is not possible. You are telling the program to get BOTH the year 2018 AND 2019. Try with the following:

```
SELECT * FROM T1
WHERE year([dt]) in (2018, 2019)
```

I hope it helps
BR

Comment: What about the current format of dt like **dd/MM/yyyy**? Is it okay to pass it as like that?

Comment: You can test it by doing a simple ´ select year(dt) from T1’ . If you get in return the year, it means that it parses it already as a date format.

Comment: Also, you can simplify you query by writing: where year(dt) in (2018, 2019)